# recv() skipping UDP packets

Tags: c, linux, udp, recv

I wrote simple program to handle incoming UDP packets. I send 60000 UDP packets to and this programm is losing packets. Bandwith about 60-70 Mbit/s.
If I wun tcpdump in parallel, then I see that all packages are received by the kernel. Also I tried recvmsg and recvmmsg with same result.

Program source code:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <signal.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
sig_atomic_t exit_cond = 0;
int sock;
void signal_handler(int signum)
{
    exit_cond = 1;
    shutdown(sock,SHUT_RDWR);
    close(sock);
}

char buff[10240];
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int len;
    unsigned long long overal;
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    signal(SIGTERM,signal_handler);
    signal(SIGINT,signal_handler);
    if(sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Error in socket()\n");
        return -1;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in rcv_addr;
    memset(&rcv_addr, 0, sizeof(rcv_addr)); 

    rcv_addr.sin_family    = AF_INET;
    rcv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    rcv_addr.sin_port = htons(1024); 
    if(bind(sock, (const struct sockaddr *)&rcv_addr,sizeof(rcv_addr)) < 0)
    { 
        printf("Error in bind()\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    while(!exit_cond)
    {
        
        len = recv(sock, (char *)buff, 10240,
                MSG_WAITALL);
        if(len > 0)
        {
            overal++;
        }
        
    }
    printf("Overal: %lld\n",overal);    
}
```

Comment: Well UDP *is* unreliable. You can drop packets even on the way between the interface and your program. One reason for that to happen is that your program simply isn't fast enough to process all incoming packets.

Comment: I normally use recvfrom for UDP.  I don't think I've ever used recv on UDP: only on TCP.

Comment: In order to verifiy @Someprogrammerdude 's assumption (recv program too slow) are you able to modify sending program by slowing it down (for example with a 1s sleep between a chink and the following one)

Comment: Another suggestion: you check `if(len > 0)`, that is correct (at least you perform some check) but you don't catch cases in which `len<0` (-1). In those cases printing `errno` (see[strerror](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) could help understanding if something strange is happening

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I run iperf3 with same bandwidth in UDP mode it works fine, without lost packets, so problem in my programm, not in system perfomance

Comment: I'm not saying it's a system performance problem, but a performance problem in your *program*. Is your *program* fast enough to process all received packages? Is the code you show the *actual* code you run? Is it a [mcve] that fully replicates the problem for you?

Comment: By the way, what is the initial value of the variable `overal`? Remember that uninitialized local variables really *are* uninitialized, and will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random or garbage) value. Perhaps if you initialize it you will get better results?

Comment: Are the packets skipped in several small chunks "inside" the whole data or just the last N bytes are missing?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, this is minimal reproducible example. Code posted in my post is actual main.c file.
Yes, I forgot to initialize overal, but this changes nothing

Comment: _I send 60000 UDP packets to and this programm is losing packets_ - how many lost packets?

Comment: `exit_cond` must be declared `volatile`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin about 1000 packets. Thanks for comment on exit_cond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. I was wrong about tcpdump, not all packets delivers to kernel. Also I did not describe the problem in detail. Program runs on single core ARM procesor, payload of UDP packets is 256 bytes, so CPU keep up with data stream, and the result kernel UDP queue owerflows, and I see packet loss. iperf3 have 1448 bytes payload, and works fine. If I decrfease iperf3 payload package to 256 bytes, it starts dropping packets as well.
To fix the problem I increased payload to 512 bytes, increased net.core.rmem_max, net.core.rmem_default and NICs ring buffers and all works fine.